# Execute 'stty raw' command in same terminal?

Tags: java, unix, console, terminal

I'm trying to put the console into "raw" mode in Java. I understand this will only work on UNIX.

I'm using the command `stty raw`

If I type the command into the terminal directly, it does what it's supposed to do. In Java, I try to set the mode like this:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("stty raw");
```

But the terminal does not go into raw mode.

I have a feeling this is because Java is just executing the command in a virtual terminal in the background or something, rather than the active terminal. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since the JVM redirects stdio/stdout/stderr, you might try something like this:

```
String[] cmd = {"/bin/sh", "-c", "stty raw </dev/tty"};
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
```

Note that stty (usually) operates on stdin not stdout.

Comment: Any chance to do this on Windows? This `</dev/tty` redirection? :/