# Trying to set terminal width/height for a program running on a tomcat server

Tags: java, linux, tomcat, terminal

So I'm trying to get data on a program through linux, and the only way the makers have given is to run a script that runs some internal commands which run prints, and then it saves them to file. The only issue is that the way it prints out the data is determinate of the terminal width/height, making it potentially unparsable if run at weird size.

I'm trying to run java code from tomcat a tomcat server that will call this script and then create the file so that I can parse the data. However, when I run the script this way, my "stty columns 10000" commands fail to change the terminal size, such that the print is stunted.

<s>The end goal is to run this as an automated task, so there won't even be a terminal and I'm wondering how this will effect the prints. I'm working on getting that up and running, but I figured I'd post this sooner than later to see if anyone has any solutions.</s>

I've done the crossed out stuff above, and the program uses the linux terminal's default sizes (80 columns, 24 rows). I managed to use stty before starting the java, and then the program reported 80 columns and 134555573 rows... lol. This stuff is all being run on root and set at boot.

Thank you

Comment: Have you seen this? You could try using this structure. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4531791/execute-stty-raw-command-in-same-terminal

Comment: Hmm, thanks. Looks like the top comment there didn't work. I'm debating working in JNI to see if i can get it working, but it looks like a bit of a nightmare to get it up, running, and incorporated with maven, and I'm not sure if it'll pan out. http://www.tricoder.net/blog/?p=197

Comment: How about calling a shell script from Java instead of trying to call `stty` followed by your own program *or* using JNI?

Comment: I encountered tty problems years ago, for that case it seems the tty from jvm is kind different from native c application. Maybe you can try use a native c application as a proxy to call script, then in the c application you can reconfigure the tty.

Comment: @ChristopherSchultz, I have the tomcat server using java code to run a shell script. The java code executes "/opt/bin/whatever.sh" and any calls to stty inside that script do nothing/print nothing (tested).

Comment: @arsane. Yeah, it looks like I might try JNI and C tomorrow, but I'm expecting to run into the same issue :/

Comment: @arsane - Was laying down to bed, and remembered something. I have access to the source code of the program that I'm trying to run the prints from, and it is C code. That program had an option to set the width/height, and it turns out its trying to run stty and fails. To summarize how that is working: java -> exec shell script -> tells C program to stty, which fails. I'm not too sure JNI will help :/

Comment: @Jdban101 a little bit tricky and boring, you can write a java program and a c program, both call the c code you write, and dump all the tty attributes and check if there is any difference, if any, try set as same. Hope that helps.

Comment: If you have the source to the C program, why not just fix it and re-build? You could have that program allow environment variables override the `stty` auto-detection and instead use them when you call-out from Java.

Comment: @arsane - I'm probably going to try that, but the outlook looks grim considering that I've already called C code that tries to do stty and fails